In the 1800s, what did they think caused the northern lights?
I watched an excellent documentary about the Franklin Expedition. It was always daytime, even when the sun was down.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora#Historical_views_and_folklore

Considering “the 1800s” have lasted 100 years, hypotheses evolved during that time. In her excellent book “Aurora,” Candace Savage details this evolution. Among other things, in 1852, Edward Sabine establishes a correlation between the number of sunspots and displays of northern lights. He supposes they are linked to the Earth’s magnetic field. This is at first met with skepticism, but by the end of the 1800s, the scientific community was mostly in agreement that there was a connection, though the explanation still had to wait until the early 1900s and more work on electromagnetism.
